# Jquery addClass() not working on loaded page

Tags: jquery

I found same question on **stackoverflow** but these answer not resolve my problem.
If i load page then jquery `$('').addClass()` not working

Please help

**html**

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.php"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.php");
  $('.home').addClass('active');
});
```

**header.php**

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="" class="home">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="about.php" class="about">About</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Project</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Location</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Faq's</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because the `load()` call is an asynchronous request. Therefore the `.home` element doesn't exist when you try to add the class to it.

You instead need to use the callback argument of `load()` to run some code *after* the AJAX request completes and the DOM has been updated, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.php", function() {
    $('.home').addClass('active');
  }); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.php");
});
```

That said, I'd strongly suggest you find an alternative method of including content in pages. Doing it on the server side is far more effective in terms of page loading speed and server strain.

Comment: please tell me one more thing how to add active class dynamic menu excluding $('.home').addClass('active');

Answer (score 2):

You have to do like this :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.php", function(){
     $('.home').addClass('active');
  }); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.php");
});
```